# Why is app.get('/') not being called? - issue with cookies and user login

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, express-session

app.get('/') not being called

Im trying to get cookies to work to let multiple users be logged in at the same time. Right now, users can log in but once they are logged in and refresh the page, they all get logged in as the same user (the one who logged in last). I think this is due to app.get('/') not being called.

This is my code. I'm sorry if it's a lot, I don't know which parts could affect the app.get function

```
let mysql = require("mysql2");

// Vi inkluderar express i vårt projekt
const express = require("express");
const sessions = require("express-session");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { SourceMap } = require("module");
const { errorMonitor } = require("events");
const { receiveMessageOnPort } = require("worker_threads");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const { match } = require("assert");
const path = require("path")

// Vi skapar en instans av vår applikation
// genom att anropa express-funktionen
const app = express();

// Vi lägger till HTTP och anropar
// dess serverfunktion och skickar med
// vår express-app
const http = require("http").Server(app);
// Vi lägger till IO, skickar med socket.io
// samt refererar http
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(cookieParser());

const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

app.use(sessions({
    secret: "secret key",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { maxage: oneDay },
    resave: false,
}))

// Vi koncentrerar datan så vi kan läsa den. Är du nyfiken
// på vad extended gör så besök body-parser på npmjs.com
// och skrolla ner till rubriken extended.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "MyPassword",
    database: "slutprojekt",
});

var session;

const dirname = './webbsidan'

console.log(__dirname)

// Vi talar om var du ska hamna när någon
// surfar in till vår webbserver. I detta fall
// kommer personen hamna i en mapp som heter
// webbsidan. Där jag kommer placera html-dokument,
// css, bilder etc.
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/webbsidan')))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('get /')
    // console.log(req)
    session = req.session;
    
    var Referer = "";
    
    if (req.rawHeaders.indexOf('Referer') != -1){
        
        Referer = req.rawHeaders[req.rawHeaders.indexOf('Referer')+1].split('/')
        Referer = Referer[Referer.length-1]
    }

    console.log(Referer)

    if (Referer != 'login.html' && !session.user){
        res.sendFile('/webbsidan/login.html', {root: __dirname})
    } else if (Referer == 'login.html' && session.user){
        res.sendFile('/webbsidan/index.html', {root: __dirname})
    }
})

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log('login-post received');    

    let sql ="SELECT * FROM användare"

    connection.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        let loggedIn = false

        for (const object of result){
            if (object.AnvändarNamn == req.body.username){
                
                if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, object.Lösenord)){
                    
                    loggedIn = true;
                    
                    session=req.session;
                    session.user=req.body.username;
                    session.userid=object.AnvändarID;
                    session.sid=req.rawHeaders[req.rawHeaders.indexOf('Cookie')+1]
                    // console.log(req.session)
                    
                    res.redirect('/');
                }
                else {
                    // console.log("fel lösenord")
                }
                break;
            }
            else {
                // console.log('användarnamnet är inte', object.AnvändarNamn);
            }
        }
        if (loggedIn == false){
            res.send('<script>alert("Login failed, try again"); window.location.replace("login.html")</script>')
        }
    })
})

app.post('/updateSchedule', (req, res) => {
    console.log('updating schedule')

    session = req.session;

    let sql1 = `SELECT * FROM kalender_tillgänglig WHERE AnvändarID = ${session.userid}`
    connection.query(sql1, function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(req.body)) {
            if (value == 'x'){
                // console.log(`${key}: ${value}`)
    
                var dateID = key.split("_")[1]
                // console.log(dateID)
                
                let sql2 = `DELETE FROM kalender_tillgänglig WHERE AnvändarID = ${session.userid} AND dateID = ${dateID}`
                connection.query(sql2, function (err, result, fields){
                    if (err) throw err;
                })
            }
            else if (value != ''){
    
                var dateID = key.split("_")[1]

                let valueString = value.toString();
            
                try {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    
                    const found = result.some(el => el.dateID == dateID) // Check if date already exists in database
                
                    let sql2 = ""

                    if (found) {
                        sql2 = `UPDATE kalender_tillgänglig SET Tillgänglig = '${valueString}' WHERE AnvändarID = ${session.userid} AND dateID = ${dateID}`;
                    } else {
                        sql2 = `INSERT INTO kalender_tillgänglig (AnvändarID, dateID, Tillgänglig) VALUES (${session.userid}, ${dateID}, '${valueString}')`
                    }

                    connection.query(sql2, function(err, result, fields) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        // console.log(sql2)
                    })
                }
                catch(e){
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
    })
    res.redirect('back');
});

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/login.html');
})

app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {

    req.session.destroy();
    // console.log(req.session);
    session = req.session;
    
    res.redirect('/login');
});

// Vi lyssnar efter att någon ansluter till 
// vår socket. När någon gör det så loggar vi
// ut att en användare har anslutit.
io.on("connection", (socket) => {

    if (session){console.log(`${session.user} anslöt.`)} else {console.log('En användare anslöt.')}

    function checkDir(){
        var splitRef = socket.handshake.headers.referer.split('\/');
            
        var newSplitRef = [];
    
        for (let i = 3; i < splitRef.length; i++){
            newSplitRef.push(splitRef[i])
        }
        splitRef = newSplitRef
        
        var splitRefString = ""
        splitRef.forEach(element => splitRefString += `/${element}`)

        return splitRefString
    }

    var currentDir = checkDir(); // Här kollas vilken sida användaren är på

    if (currentDir == "/login.html") { // om användaren är på login sidan men redan är inloggad omdirigeras den till startsidan
        if (session != undefined){
            io.emit("redirect", '/')
        }
    }
    else if (session == undefined){ // om användaren inte är inloggad omdirigeras den till login-sidan
        io.emit("redirect", '/login')
    }
    else if ((currentDir == "/") || (currentDir == "/index.html")){ // om användaren är inloggad på startsidan visas en lista med alla användare
        console.log(session)

        connection.connect(function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
    
            let sql = "SELECT * FROM användare"
            connection.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;

                io.emit("result", result);
            })
        });
    }
    else if (currentDir == "/mySchedule.html"){ // om användaren är inloggad på mySchedule sidan ritas kalendern 
        connection.connect(function (err) { // upp med de tiderna användaren redan fyllt i att den är tillgänglig
            if (err) throw err;

            let sql1 = `SELECT * FROM kalender`
            connection.query(sql1, function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                io.emit("result", result);
            })

            let sql2 = `SELECT * FROM kalender_tillgänglig WHERE AnvändarID = ${session.userid}`
            connection.query(sql2, function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                // console.log(result)
                io.emit("availability", result);
            })
        });
    }
    else if (currentDir == "/avlblPT.html"){
        connection.connect(function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            let sql0 = `SELECT * FROM kalender`
            connection.query(sql0, function (err, result0, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                io.emit("result", result0);
            })

            let sql1 = `SELECT AnvändarID FROM användare`
            connection.query(sql1, function (err, result1, fields){
                if (err) throw err;

                var userCount = result1.length
            
                var dateIDList = []

                let sql2 = `SELECT dateID, COUNT(dateID) FROM kalender_tillgänglig WHERE Tillgänglig <> 'x' GROUP BY dateID HAVING COUNT(dateID) > ${userCount-1}`
                connection.query(sql2, function (err, result2, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    // console.log("res:",result2)
                    result2.forEach(element => {
                        dateIDList.push(element.dateID)
                    })
                    // console.log(dateIDList)
                    dateIDList.forEach(elem => {
                        let sql3 = `SELECT * FROM kalender_tillgänglig WHERE dateID = ${elem}`
                        connection.query(sql3, function(err, result3, fields) { //finner varje datum (ett i taget) där alla är tillgängliga
                            if (err) throw err;
                            
                            var usersHours = []

                            result3.forEach(user => { // loopar igenom användare, här börjar uträkningen för att lista ut vilka timmar alla är tillgängliga 
                                const availablePasses = user.Tillgänglig.split(', ')
                                var availableHours = []
                                
                                availablePasses.forEach(pass => {
                                    const startStop = pass.split("-")
                                    const start = Number(startStop[0])
                                    const stop = Number(startStop[1])
                                    
                                    for (let i = start; i < stop; i++){
                                        availableHours.push(i)
                                    }
                                })

                                usersHours.push({'AnvändarID': user.AnvändarID, 'Tillgänglig': availableHours})
                            })

                            var intersection = usersHours[0].Tillgänglig // detta kodstycke kollar vilka timmar som finns i alla användares tillgänglighetslistor
                            for (let i = 1; i < usersHours.length; i++){
                                intersection = intersection.filter(element => usersHours[i].Tillgänglig.includes(element));
                            }
                            
                            var passes = []

                            function pushTime(pass, tIndex) {
                                passes[pass].push(intersection[tIndex])
                            }

                            function addPass(passIndex) {
                                passes.push([])
                                
                                passIndex += 1
                                return passIndex
                            }

                            var pass = 0
                            addPass(0)

                            for (let j = 0; j < intersection.length; j++){ // detta ska dela upp intersection i pass om det behövs
                                if (j+1 < intersection.length){
                                    if (intersection[j]+1 == intersection[j+1]){
                                        pushTime(pass, j)
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        pushTime(pass, j)
                                        pass = addPass(pass)
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    pushTime(pass, j)
                                }
                            }
                            console.log("done calculating",passes)

                            let sql4 = `SELECT * FROM alla_tillgängliga`

                            connection.query(sql4, function(err, result4, fields) {
                                if (err) throw err;

                                // console.log(result4)

                                // Detta block kallas två gånger. Inte stort problem, bara onödigt
                                // Detta block kollar om det finns några dagar i alla_tillgängliga tabellen där inte alla är tillgängliga
                                result4.forEach(elem => {
                                    // console.log(elem.dateID)
                                    if (dateIDList.includes(elem.dateID) == false){
                                        // console.log(`dateID ${elem.dateID} should be removed from table`)

                                        let sql7 = `DELETE FROM alla_tillgängliga WHERE dateID = '${elem.dateID}'`

                                        connection.query(sql7, function (err, result7, fields) {
                                            if (err) throw err;
                                        })
                                    }
                                })

                                if (passes[0][0]){
                                    // console.log("everyone is available at the same time")
                                    var passStrings = []
                                    passes.forEach(pass => {
                                        var stringStart = pass[0].toString()
                                        var stringStop = (pass[0]+pass.length).toString()
                                        
                                        passStrings.push(`${stringStart}-${stringStop}`)
                                    })

                                    var availabilityString = passStrings.join(", ")
                                    // console.log(availabilityString)

                                    var dateID = result3[0].dateID

                                    const found = result4.some(el => el.dateID == dateID) // Check if date already exists in database
                                
                                    let sql5 = ""

                                    if (found) {
                                        sql5 = `UPDATE alla_tillgängliga SET tider = '${availabilityString}' WHERE dateID = ${dateID}`
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        sql5 = `INSERT INTO alla_tillgängliga (dateID, tider) VALUES (${dateID}, '${availabilityString}')`
                                    }

                                    connection.query(sql5, function(err, result5, fields) {
                                        if (err) throw err;

                                        let sql6 = `SELECT * FROM alla_tillgängliga`

                                        connection.query(sql6, function(err, result6, fields) {
                                            if (err) throw err;

                                            io.emit("availability", result6);
                                        })
                                    })
                                    
                                } else {
                                    // console.log("there is no time during the day where everyone is available")
                                }
                            })

                            
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    }

    
})

// Istället för app.listen kör vi nu http.listen
http.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Servern körs, besök http://localhost:3000");
});

function genDates(start, end){
    var getDaysArray = function(start, end) {
        for(var arr=[],dt=new Date(start); dt<=new Date(end); dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1)){
            arr.push(new Date(dt));
        }
        return arr;
    };

    var newStart = start.toISOString().replace("00:00:00", "10:10:10") // specify time so that no date is skipped or repeated when 
    var newEnd = end.toISOString().replace("00:00:00", "10:10:10") // time is shifted in march and october
    
    var daylist = getDaysArray(newStart, newEnd);

    var datelist= []

    daylist.forEach(element => {
        datelist.push(element.toISOString().split("T")[0])
    })

    var dowNameList = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];

    let sql1 = `SELECT dateID, fullDate FROM kalender`
    connection.query(sql1, function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        
        for (let i = 0; i < daylist.length; i++){
            
            var dowName = daylist[i].toString().split(" ")[0]
            var dowNum = dowNameList.indexOf(dowName)
            
            dowNum += 1
            
            const found = result.some(el => el.fullDate == datelist[i]) // Check if date already exists in database
            
            if (!found){
                let sql2 = `INSERT INTO kalender (dateID, fullDate, dowName, dowNum) VALUES (${i+1}, '${datelist[i]}', '${dowName}', ${dowNum});`
                connection.query(sql2, function (err, result, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                })
            }
        }
    })

    
}

genDates(new Date("2023-01-01"),new Date("2023-12-31"));
```

Comment: i've been testing with one user using chrome and one using firefox

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are ending the request in get(/) ? If at some point both below conditions are false

```
if (Referer != 'login.html' && !session.user){
    res.sendFile('/webbsidan/login.html', {root: __dirname})
} else if (Referer == 'login.html' && session.user){
    res.sendFile('/webbsidan/index.html', {root: __dirname})
}
```

you're not ending the connection. Try to put a default response, like at the end of get()

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
... codes

res.send()
}
```

or, change the `else if` to `else`

```
if (Referer != 'login.html' && !session.user){
        res.sendFile('/webbsidan/login.html', {root: __dirname})
    } else {
        res.sendFile('/webbsidan/index.html', {root: __dirname})
    }
```

Comment: i tried adding `res.send()` to the request but i still have the problem that `app.get('/')` isn't called at all

Comment: Try Changing "else if" to "else" as in my answer

Comment: Also to check if its called, put console.log() in get(/)

Comment: i have a console.log already, if i change "else if" to "else" it wont make sure that the user is actually logged in before sending to index.html

Comment: the end of app.get now looks like this:

```if (Referer != 'login.html' && !session.user){
        res.sendFile('/webbsidan/login.html', {root: __dirname})
    } else if (session.user){
        res.sendFile('/webbsidan/index.html', {root: __dirname})
    } 

    res.send()```